# Javascript works in chrome but not in IE

Tags: javascript, html

If you render the code below in chrome, you will see this adds fine but if you use IE, the rows doesn't get added. Could you tell me what am I doing wrong here that its not working in IE? When I add a new row in IE, my new row doesn't add the controls. This works fine in chrome and firefox but not in IE. I couldn't find anything wrong in the code unless I am missing something particular to IE. I appreciate for your help.

```
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function insertAdditional() {
        var type = document.getElementById('additional_type').value;
        var node = document.createElement('li');
        node.innerHTML = document.getElementById(type + 'Form').innerHTML;
        document.getElementById('additional').appendChild(node);
    }


    function addRow(tableID) {

        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var element1 = document.createElement("input");
        element1.type = "checkbox";
        element1.name = "chkbox[]";
        cell1.appendChild(element1);

        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var element2 = document.createElement("input");
        element2.type = "date";
        element2.size = "12";
        element2.maxlength = "10";
        element2.placeholder = "YYYY-MM-DD";
        element2.name = "entrydate[]";
        cell2.appendChild(element2);

        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        var element3 = document.createElement("input");
        element3.type = "date";
        element3.size = "12";
        element3.maxlength = "10";
        element3.placeholder = "YYYY-MM-DD";
        element3.name = "eventdate[]";
        cell3.appendChild(element3);


        var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
        var element4 = document.createElement("textarea");
        element4.type = "text";
        element4.name = "comment[]";
        element4.rows = "4";
        element4.cols = "60";
        cell4.appendChild(element4);

    }

    function deleteRow(tableID) {
        try {
            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;

            for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
                var row = table.rows[i];
                var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
                if (null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
                    table.deleteRow(i);
                    rowCount--;
                    i--;
                }


            }
        } catch (e) {
            alert(e);
        }
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>
    Comments</h1>
<div>
    <input type="button" value="Add Comment" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />
    <input type="button" value="Delete Comment" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />     </div>
<table id="dataTable" width="1024px" border="1" cellpadding="10">
    <tr>
        <th>
            <center>
                Choose</center>
        </th>
        <th>
            <center>
                Entry Date</center>
        </th>
        <th>
            <center>
                Event Date</center>
        </th>
        <th>
            <center>
                Comment</center>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="date" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" size="12" maxlength="10" name="entrydate[]" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="date" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" size="12" maxlength="10" name="eventdate[]" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <textarea rows="4" cols="60" maxlength="500" name="comment[]"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: *"...if you use IE, the rows doesn't get added... When I add a new row in IE, my new row doesn't add the controls..."* Which is it? The row doesn't get added, or it does get added but the controls don't?

Comment: sorry, yes the controls don't get added in IE.

Comment: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NKV8M/) for those who want to easily reproduce.

Comment: Cut down to general testcase (with comments) http://jsbin.com/egejoy/2/edit (fails in IE10).

Comment: @bladerunner: First place to look when you're having trouble is in the console that's in the developer tools included in the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internet Explorer (even 10) does not support input element of type *date*. More than that: when trying to assign such type (or any other non supported type) to dynamically created input element, JavaScript will crash with error and the code execution will stop at that point.

To overcome this and default back to *text* type when the browser is not supporting the desired type, use `.setAttribute()` method instead of direct assignment:

```
element2.setAttribute("type", "date");
```

This tip and much more can be found [here](http://diveintohtml5.info/detect.html).

Answer (score 4):

Because [IE has no support for date inputs](http://caniuse.com/input-datetime) nor does any browser besides Opera and a few recent ones. Chrome has partial support, [which started at Chrome 20](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/08/Quick-FAQs-on-input-type-date-in-Google-Chrome).

As pointed out in the comments, IE is somewhat problematic when changing the input types. IE does default to `text`, but to avoid issues, [IE's `createElement` accepts an HTML string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536389%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) where you can define the type:

```
//creating a radio button
var newRadioButton = document.createElement("<input type='radio' />");
```

Comment: Would this prevent the inputs from being added, or would they just get the default type?

Comment: @squint they will default to text. The OP didn't say anything about what happened to it though, if they turned into text inputs. If they didn't, it's a whole new story.

Comment: Any chance this feature will be supported by firefox soon? Not that I use it, but it _is_ a decent browser.

Comment: `foo.type = "date"` causes an error when I try it in the IE Javascript console.

Comment: @Barmar: I wonder if it gives an error when doing `foo.type = "checkbox"`. I know IE is finicky about changing an input's type.

Comment: I wasn't changing the type, I was setting the initial type. `foo.type = "text"` worked fine.

Comment: @Barmar: Except that there's a default of `"text"`, so I was wondering if IE was considering it a change. Doing `foo.type = "text"` wouldn't be a change.

Comment: @squint If that were a problem, his code would stop when it tries to set `element1.type = "checkbox"`. But it doesn't fail until it tries to set the date element.

Comment: @Barmar: It wasn't clear to me from the question where it was failing, but yes, I tested it and the error states `"Invalid argument"`, which I also get if I try to set `"foo"`, but not `"checkbox"`. The error message is different when trying to change the type after it has been manually set once, or if it's been added to the DOM already: `"This command is not supported"`

Comment: @squint True, the question wasn't precise. I copied his code to jsfiddle.net, and saw that the checkbox was created but the date field wasn't. http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/dPsWT/

Comment: I apologize for not being so clear. I should have asked you to use jsfiddle and see the result in IE. But ShadowWizard's answer has fixed this bug in IE. Thanks everyone for all your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
try {
    element2.type = "date";
} catch(e) {
    element2.type = "text";
}
```

This will use a `date` input on browsers that support it, and fall back to `text` on others.

Comment: Good idea, but see [here](http://diveintohtml5.info/detect.html) a better way: `element2.setAttribute("type", "date");` which will default to "text" by itself without any errors thrown around.

Comment: @ShadowWizard You should put that as an answer

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Your solution has fixed the problem in IE. Could you please post this as an answer so I could mark this as a solution. Thanks a bunch!!